# How use JavaScript to query on selector result properly?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have the following piece of HTML.

```
<div id="outer"><b class="dest">something</b>
    <div id="test"><b class="dest">unwanted stuff</b></div>
</div>
```

Let's say I already have a reference to the `outer` element with `document.querySelector("#outer")`. How can I query all `b` elements with the `dest` class and are the first child of its parent? I tried `document.querySelector("#outer").querySelector("b.dest")` and `document.querySelector("#outer").querySelector("b.dest:first-child")` but only the first `b` element has returned. How can I get both `b` elements (through the result of `document.querySelector("#outer")`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.querySelector` only selects one element max.

`.querySelectorAll` Returns an array-like node list.

You want:

```
var bElements = document.getElementById("outer").querySelectorAll('b.dest:first-child');
```

This will return an array of all elements that:

- Have a parent with an id of `outer`
- have the class `dest`
- are the **first-child** of their parent

Then you can access each element just like an array, ex.

```
bElements[0]
```

DEMO:

```js
var bElements = document.getElementById("outer").querySelectorAll('b.dest:first-child');

console.log(bElements)
```

```html
<div id="outer"><b class="dest">something</b>
    <div id="test"><b class="dest">unwanted stuff</b></div>
</div>
```